# Taylor Series of $g(x)=f(x^3)$

Tags: taylor-expansion

Question:

Let $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be infinitely differentiable and let $P_n(t)$ be it's Taylor Series of order $n$ about $x=0$.

Let $g(x)=f(x^3)$.

Show that $Q(t)=P_n(t^3)$ is the Taylor Series of order $3n$ for $g$ about $x=0$.

As for what I've tried:

I followed my instincts and wrote out the series of differentials for $g(x)$ to see what comes out, but I got a lot of terms and can't find a way to connect it to it's Taylor Series:

$g^{(n)}(x)=((3x^2)f'(x^3))^{(n-1)}=((6x)f'(x^3)+(9x^4)f''(x^3))^{(n-2)}=((6)f'(x^3)+(54x^3)f''(x^3)+(27x^6)f'''(x^3))^{(n-3)}$

Not sure how to go about this problem.
Any ideas?

Comment: You'll get better answers here if you tell us more about what you already know. What are your thoughts on this question?

Comment: I guess you must use induction over $n$ and show what is the form of $g^{(n)}(0)$